# Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByRemovingPercentEncoding in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3

After upgrading my Xcode to Swift 3, I'm getting this error:

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'stringByRemovingPercentEncoding'

What is the alternative for `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` in Swift 3?

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: Take a look at [SE-0006: Apply API Guidelines to the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md), all the standard library name changes for Swift 3 are documented there. If in doubt, you can always take advantage of Xcode's autocomplete by just typing `str.percen...`

Comment: @Hamish thank you for the link ..I will check for future errors to convert..

Comment: reason for down votes even after receiving answer??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `removingPercentEncoding` in Swift 3.

```
let str = string.removingPercentEncoding
```

For more detail read [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642934-removingpercentencoding).